# Traducir codigo a java

Tags: java, diccionarios, hashmap

Tengo que traducir este codigo python a java, pero no encuentro la forma de traducir las otras partes.
Se trata de un traductor de español a ingés en codigo java, ya lo tengo hecho en python pero el problema viene a la hora de traducirlo a java, ya que este usa otro tipo de sintaxis.
Python:

```
traductor = {}

opcion = -1

while opcion != 3:
   print("1)   Introducir palabras en español y su "
     "equivalente en ingles.")
   print("2)   Introducir una frase y mostrar la misma"
     " frase sustituyendo las palabras que pueda"
     " al ingles.")
   print("3)   Salir.")
opcion = int(input("Selecciona una opción"))
if opcion not in [1,2,3]:
   print("Opción inválida")

if opcion == 1:
   palabra_esp = input("Introduce una palabra en español")
   palabra_ing = input("Introduce su equivalente en inglés")
   traductor[palabra_esp] = palabra_ing

if opcion == 2:
   frase = input("Introduce una frase")
   palabras = frase.split(" ")
   i = 0
   while i < len(palabras):
       palabras[i]
       if palabras[i] in traductor.keys():
           palabras[i] = traductor[palabras[i]]
       i += 1

   texto_tra = " ".join(palabras)
   print(texto_tra)
```

Y este es mi codigo de Java, no consigo traducir la opcion 2 ni la 3 que la tengo a medias:

```
System.out.println("Ejercicio 6");
        HashMap<String, String> traductor = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Scanner sc6 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion = -1;
        while (opcion != 3);
            System.out.println("1)   Introducir palabras en español y su \"\n" +
"       \"equivalente en ingles.");
            System.out.println("2)   Introducir una frase y mostrar la misma\"\n" +
"       \" frase sustituyendo las palabras que pueda\"\n" +
"       \" al ingles.");
            System.out.println("3)   Salir.");
        System.out.println("Introduce una opcion");
        opcion = sc6.nextInt();
        sc6.nextLine();
        if (opcion==1);
            System.out.println("Introduce una palabra en español");
            String espanyol = sc6.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce una palabra en ingles");
            String ingles = sc6.nextLine();
            traductor.put(espanyol, ingles);
        if (opcion==2);
            System.out.println("Introduce una frase");
            String frase = sc6.nextLine();
            String[] palabras = frase.split(" ");
            int l = 0;
            Set<String> keys = traductor.keySet();
            while (l<palabras.length);
                palabras[l];
```

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas hacer uso del hashmap que has creado:

```
if (opcion==2){
  System.out.println("Introduce una frase");
            String frase = sc6.nextLine();
            String[] palabras = frase.split(' ');
            int l = 0;
            
            while (l<palabras.length){
              if(traductor.containsKey(palabras[l])){
                palabras[l] = traductor.get(palabras[l]);
     }
            l++
  }
                
}
```

Recuerda también poner los corchetes para delimitar los bucles y los ifs.

```
if (opcion==1){
            System.out.println("Introduce una palabra en español");
            String espanyol = sc6.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce una palabra en ingles");
            String ingles = sc6.nextLine();
            traductor.put(espanyol, ingles);
}
```

Comment: Me da el siguiente error: cannot find that symbol. En el traductor.contains. Y no se como hacer para la opcion 3 de salir

Comment: Es containsKey(). Cual es la opcion 3? Me la indicas en tu pregunta?